# Font-Awesome not showing in browser

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

My website is showing one icon but not another two, the code is the same but not showing
This is the css bit

This is the code for the non working part

```
  <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"> </i><span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i> <span class="network-name">Github</span></a></li>
```

This is the code for the bit that works

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated" style="color: #DC09BD"></i>
```

However if i change the twitter to say the working one it shows.

The css shows the .fa-twitter

```
.fa-twitter:before {
  content: "\f099"; }

.fa-twitter-square:before {
  content: "\f081"; }
```

Any one with ideas?

I have also disabled ad block

Thanks

Comment: Are you including FA somewhere?

Comment: which version ?

Comment: latest download last night @temaniafif

Comment: ah download ... so included correctly ? and what about CDN ?

Comment: sorry CDN? Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @DavidCook Are you including FA? If not, that's your problem. Just repeating this since you haven't answered.

Comment: Yes i am using the fa as shows in the code snippet @jhpratt

Comment: @DavidCook The snippet does not indicate that you're including FA.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this : Is this what you want ?** [Execution](http://jdoodle.com/h/5h)

**HTML:**

```
<html>
   <head>

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

</head>
   <body>

<li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" targ="_blank">
<i class="fab fa-twitter"> </i>
<span class="network-name">Twitter</span>
</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github-alt"></i> <span class="network-name">Github</span></a></li>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated" style="color: #DC09BD"></i>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .fa-twitter:before {
  content: "\f099"; }

.fa-twitter-square:before {
  content: "\f081"; }
```

If this is what you want then you were loading the wrong class name.
eg: it's not  `<i class="fa fa-twitter">`, It's `<i class="fab fa-twitter">`

Comment: I have tried this and now I have a flashing ?  and ! which takes it in returns any idea what happening now?

Comment: Sorry didn't see the text below, just changed from fa to fab and it works

Comment: Hi @DavidCook, I hope my answer helped  :)

Comment: Yes @Abhi it did help and sorted the issue. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, Kindly mark the answer as correct or up-vote for future readers :)